# Как задать конкретный адрес с помощью new с адресацией?

Tags: c++, память, выделение-памяти, new

В C++ есть операция new с адресацией, с помощью которой можно выделить конкретную область памяти. Но не совсем понятно, можно ли выделить конкретный адрес.
При попытке такое сделать (см. строчку ниже):

```
char *pt = new (0x000000) int(10);
```

Возникает ошибка ***"operator new: ни одна перегруженная функция не может преобразовать все типы аргументов".***
Как можно задать конкретный адрес, как было указано сверху?

Comment: А откуда вы знаете, что адрес `0x000000` уже не используется для хранения чего-нибудь?

Comment: @wololo Вы хотите сказать, что он будет занят и ничего туда нельзя будет записать? Вероятно, да, но вопрос никуда не исчезает. Есть ли вообще такая возможность в языке? Можно ли указать конкретный адрес и попытаться туда что-либо записать?

Comment: Ну, попробуйте: `char* pt = reinterpret_cast<char*>(0x000000); *pt = 1;`

Comment: @wololo Спасибо, теперь всё стало на свои места :)

Comment: `# include <new>
int main(){
int *pt = new (0x000000) int(10);
}`

Comment: В placement new необходимо передавать указатель на `void`, а не целое число, и включить заголовочный файл `new`, чтобы соотв. стандартная функция аллокации стала объявлена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой оператор называется "placement new" и он на самом деле **не выделяет память совсем!** Всё, что он делает - вызывает конструктор на уже существующей памяти. В оператор надо передавать указатель на память, а не число.

Т.е., если вы выделите память с помощью `malloc`, `mmap`, `VirtualAlloc` или чем-то подобным - то вы можете потом в этой памяти создать объект. Можно выделить сразу много памяти, и потом в ней создавать объекты - `std::vector`, например, так и работает.

У этого оператора также нет парного `delete` - вместо этого надо просто вызвать деструктор: `ptr->~Object()`.